# contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException:

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Error on run time:

```
index.jsp(12,8) PWC6038: "${sqlStatement == null}" contains invalid expression(s):
javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type:
    org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: : javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

Questions:

1. How would I go about debugging this?
2. Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl  <-- what does this mean?

This is what I have

- NetBeans IDE 7.3
- Tomcat 7.0
- MySql connection

This is a simple sql gateway from Murach's book

index.jsp

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 

    <c:if test="${sqlStatement == null}">
        <c:set var="sqlStatment" value="select * from User" />
    </c:if>

    <h1>The SQL Gateway</h1>
    <p>Enter an SQL statement and click the execute button. Then, information about the<br/>
    statement will appear at the bottom of this page.
    </p>

    <p><b>SQL Statement:</b></p>

    <form action="SqlGateway" method="POST">

        <textarea name="sqlStatement" cols="60" rows="8">${sqlStatement}</textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute">

    </form>

    <p><b>SQL result:</b></p>
    <p>${sqlResult}</p>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SqlGatewayServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sql.SqlGatewayServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SqlGatewayServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SqlGateway</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with the servlet, but if you need me to post it please let me know.

Comment: What is the version of Tomcat referenced in the book?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the EL library. Are you developing this project using maven or is it created as a web project?

Comment: Tomcat 6.x.  Thanks for replying

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza its a web project

Comment: So, why do you running it on 7?

Comment: @RomanC what's your point? The application should run fine on both Tomcat 6 and 7.

Comment: @RomanC because it was the newest.... hummm is there that much a change between tomcat 6 and 7?

Comment: @EricHuang Ofcourse 7 has newer API libs.

Comment: @RomanC yes, but none of those new libraries will make the EL and JSTL code here invalid, so I'll remark that this application **should work** with no problems in both Tomcat 6 and 7.

Comment: @EricHuang Your JSP looks good, if you have prebuild war file you should run it first, and also post the web.xml, at least will not log to the archives for examples.

Comment: @RomanC I edited and posted web.xml.  Sorry I am a beginner, what do you mean run war file first? Could you be kind and walk me through? or a reference link... thank you

Comment: First of all use maven, then add all jstl dependencies to project

Comment: @maks why to use maven? I just copied/pasted this code and dropped in a new JSP and deployed it on my Tomcat 5.5 and run with no problems. And no, I don't use maven at all :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could it be something wrong with my el-api.jar file?

Comment: @Luiggi: with maven you will have less problems with dependencies in future

Comment: @maks if you know what you're doing, you won't have any problems at all.

Comment: @Luiggi so why are you asking here? :)

Comment: @maks in order to understand how OP adds/removes libraries to the build path of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Could it be something wrong with my el-api.jar file*

You should **not** have any servletcontainer-specific JAR file in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. Servletcontainer-specific JAR files are supposed to be already provided by the servlet-container itself.

Look in Tomcat's `/lib` folder, it already ships internal libraries, JSP, Servlet and EL libraries. You do not need to supply any of them via your webapp. If you still do it, the runtime classpath may end up in a disaster because there are duplicate different versioned libraries. In your specific case, you likely supplied a randomly downloaded EL API via your webapp which didn't match the EL impl found in the runtime classpath and thus the right impl can't be found via the abstract factory pattern.

So, if you get rid of servletcontainer-specific JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`, then all should be well. The `/WEB-INF/lib` should contain **only** libraries which are specific to the webapp itself and are not already provided by the servletcontainer.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  when I mentioned el-api.jar file I was looking at Tomcat's lib folder.  I do not have el-api.jar in my /WEB-INF/Lib.  The reason I suspect something wrong with the jar is because... well, its just an odd weird problem I am having right now....   But thank you for giving your input...

Comment: That's odd. At least, fact is, your runtime classpath is a mess. Have you ever fiddled around with loose servletcontainer-specific JAR files? E.g. in JDK/JRE's `/lib` or `/lib/ext` in a careless attempt to fix compilation errors?

Comment: I wish I did, then I at least I know I did something bad.... I am going to re-install tomcat and my IDE, see if it fixes things...  Thank you